# Global variable value assignment remains the same after re-assignment in function (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

programmers, I am very new to android studio and java, in this case, I am trying to upload retrieved user info and store them in firebase database. the retrieve process is successful, and the retrieve URL can be seen after logged. However, the `String pathToProfile` is not assigned with the URL, when I checked the log, it is null. Thanks in advance!

Global declaration:

```
String pathToProfile;
Map<String, Object> UserInfo = new HashMap<>();
```

Function to retrieve the download URL

```
// retrieved URL should be saved in user document
    private void retrieveProfileViaURL () {
        profileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                pathToProfile = uri.toString();
                UserInfo.put(PROFILE_URL, pathToProfile);
                Log.d(TAG, "retrieve profile image successful" + pathToProfile);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "retrieve profile image failure");
                // pathToProfile = "uri download unsuccessful";
            }
        });
    }
```

Function to upload userinformation to firebase

```
private void uploadUserInfo(String user, String bioInfo) {
        // CollectionReference users = db.collection("users");
        String UID = getUserID();
        retrieveProfileViaURL();

        // UserInfo.put(USERID, UID);
        UserInfo.put(USERNAME, user);
        UserInfo.put(BIO, bioInfo);


        mDocRef.collection("users").document(UID).set(UserInfo)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.d(USER_INFO, "Document has been saved");
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(USER_INFO, "Document was not saved!", e);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Where is the "global declaration" actually declared? There is no such thing as a "global" variable in Java.

Answer (score 1):

All data from the Firebase Database is read asynchronously. You can not get values outside the call. That's why your `pathToProfile` shows null.

For Better approach you can try something like this.

After the user upload the data it will automatically allow user to write in data with url

```
private void retrieveProfileViaURL () {
    profileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            pathToProfile = uri.toString();
            String UID = getUserID();
            UserInfo.put(USERNAME, user);
            UserInfo.put(BIO, bioInfo);
            UserInfo.put(PROFILE_URL, pathToProfile);
            mDocRef.collection("users").document(UID).set(UserInfo)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.d(USER_INFO, "Document has been saved");
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(USER_INFO, "Document was not saved!", e);
                }
            });
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, "retrieve profile image failure");
            // pathToProfile = "uri download unsuccessful";
        }
    });
}
```